# Symfony 5, route match but dont found in url

Tags: parameters, routes, get, match, symfony5

Hello my route matche but doesnt work wuth url example

https://localhost:8000/activate/?salt=606842b65dc19/20

I have run the `php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup`
like a related problem but stil doesnt work, i really want to recupe the salt.

```
C:\RICSYMFONY\RIC>php bin/console router:match /activate/?salt=156116/8

 [OK] Route "app_activation" matches

+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                      |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | app_activation                                             |
| Path         | /activate/{salt}/{id}                                      |
| Path Regex   | {^/activate/(?P<salt>[^/]++)/(?P<id>[^/]++)$}sDu           |
| Host         | ANY                                                        |
| Host Regex   |                                                            |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                        |
| Method       | ANY                                                        |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                  |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                            |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::activate() |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler    |
|              | utf8: true                                                 |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

   /**
     * @Route("/activate/{salt}/{id}", name="app_activation")
     */
    public function activate (Personne $personne){
       $salt= $_GET["salt"];
    ...
    }
```

An the error I have,

```
ResourceNotFoundException  NotFoundHttpException
HTTP 404 Not Found
No route found for "GET /activate/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found with researching motor how doing, and i finally do like that, and that do the work, with a optional -- {id} -->Personne --- to not get exception of not found it.

```
   /**
     * @Route("/activate/{salt}/{id}", name="app_activation")
     */
    public function activate ($salt,? Personne $personne){
         $salt
    ....
    }
```